# How to use ant design icons without NPM in Visual studio

Tags: reactjs, antd

As title.
I'm developing a web system for customers use react.js and Ant Design.
So many items are required NPM to download.
I use Visual Studio to develop ASP.Net web systems under Windows platform, so I wonder if I can understand what is should be added into the project and what is shouldn't inside what I downloaded from NPM.  Furthermore, I need to deploy my product to a test site or even to customers.
I've read [Use of Ant Design Icons While Offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59394428/use-of-ant-design-icons-while-offline) but I don't know what is I really needed because of my poor English.  I've downloaded Ant-design-icons by NPM, but I failed to add it to my project because it make my Visual Studio busy and no response.  I've tried to add the contents of the "dist" folder in the package downloaded by NPM, and I got 1 error per 1 ts file while compiling.  Could I have a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html) for a quickstart to react.

Simply type (in terminal. in some directory):

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm i antd @ant-design/icons
npm start
```

This will initialize a new react app in a folder called my-app (you can change the name if you wish), change into that directory, install ant design and the icons package. and start the dev server.

That should be enough to be able to get started using Ant Design.

If you are having npm trouble, try [yarn](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/).

Same idea:

```
yarn create react-app my-app
cd my-app
yarn add antd @ant-design/icons
yarn start
```